# How to Validate Form Fields and then Insert into database by clicking once on submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to validate form fields and then insert the form data into a database. My form submits after clicking the submit button twice after all field values are correct. Actually Form fields are validated and action change by click on submit button once. When action is set then clicking on submit button submits the form.

Can anybody tell me how it can be submitted by clicking submit button only once.

Here is my html code with validation php script on same file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style> .error {color:#ff0000;} </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        $companyNameErr = $addressErr = $emailErr = $contactErr = "";
        $companyName = $address = $email = $contact = $description = "";
        function test_data($data)
        {
            $data=trim($data);
            $data=stripslashes($data);
            $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }
        $errors = array();
        $valid=0; 
        if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] =="POST" )
        {

            $companyName=$_POST["companyName"];
            if( empty($companyName) )
            {
                $companyNameErr = "Please Enter Company Name";
                $errors[]= $companyNameErr ;
            }
            else
            {
                if( !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$companyName) )
                {
                    $companyNameErr = "Invalid Company Name";
                    $errors[]= $companyNameErr ;
                }
                else
                {
                    $companyName=test_data($companyName);
                    $valid++;

                }
            }
            $address=$_POST["address"];
            if( empty($address) )
            {
                $addressErr = "Please Enter Address";
                $errors[]= $addressErr ;
            }
            else
            { 
                $address=test_data($address);
                $valid++;
            }
            $email=$_POST["email"];
            if( empty($email) )
            {
                $emailErr = "Please Enter Email";
                $errors[]= $emailErr ;
            }
            else
            {
                if( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
                {
                    $emailErr = "Invalid Email";
                    $errors[]= $emailErr ;
                }
                else
                {
                    $email=test_data($email);
                    $valid++;
                }   
            }       
            $contact=$_POST["contact"];
            if( empty($contact) )
            {
                $contactErr = "Please Enter Contact Number";
                $errors[]= $contactErr ;
            }
            else
            { 
                if( !preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$contact ) )
                {
                    $contactErr = "Invalid Contact";
                    $errors[]= $contactErr ;
                }
                else
                {
                    $contact=test_data($contact);
                    $valid++;
                }   
            }
    }
    if($valid==4)
    {

    }
    ?>
    <form name="myform" method="post" action="<?php if($valid < 4){ echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; }else{ echo "validate1.php"; }?>" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Company Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="companyName" value ="<?php if(isset($_POST['companyName']) && empty($companyNameErr)){ echo $_POST['companyName'];} else {echo '';}?>" required ><span class="error"><sup>*</sup><?php echo $companyNameErr; ?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="address" value ="<?php if(isset($_POST['address']) && empty($addressErr)){ echo $_POST['address'];} else {echo '';}?>" required><span class="error"><sup>*</sup><?php echo $addressErr; ?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" value ="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']) && empty($emailErr)){ echo $_POST['email'];} else {echo '';}?>" required><span class="error"><sup>*</sup><?php echo $emailErr; ?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contact</td>
                <td>+91-<input type="text" name="contact" value ="<?php if(isset($_POST['contact']) && empty($contactErr)){ echo $_POST['contact'];} else {echo '';}?>" required maxlength="10" minlength="10"><span class="error"><sup>*</sup><?php echo $contactErr; ?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td><textarea name="description" cols="60" rows="3"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="next>>">
    </form>
</body>
```

php code specifying connection with and then inserting values into database is in another file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>    
<?php 
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 'mydatabase');
    if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $conn->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `MyDataBase`"); 
    $conn->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyDataBase.company_details( `comp_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`company_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,`address` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,`email` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,`contact` INT(13) NOT NULL,`description` VARCHAR(150))");
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO company_details (company_name, address, email, contact, description ) VALUES ( '".$_POST['companyName']."', '".$_POST['address']."', '".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['contact']."', '".$_POST['description']."')");
    $conn->close();
?>
</body>
```

Comment: did not helped me.the problem is different

Answer (score 1):

there re many nice frameworks out there why you want to create that validation things by your own in a old way like many years before without oop. mvc is something nice.

**back to topic**

your $valid will be 0 on firstcall..
you only have $_POST on a actual submit with data.
the form action is validate1.php
the php_sef is the same page so i dont get what you want to do with that if there. it will be alsways validate1.php.
where do you actualy insert the database. and why is the database insert not validated. the validation need to be done before you insert data not before you output a from. 
dont forget unfiltered php_self is insecure and allows xss

data flow:

- if method = post validate data

  - if no error do database update.
  - else we have validation errors so output them.
- else we have no post so just display the form

to block a form is useless because everyone can reload the page and submit again. just output the errors and give him another chance. if ou want to disable it you need to have some access controll. if you just want a easy disable and show it to the user set the submit to disabled or action to #

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the order of what you are doing.

1. User enters form data
2. Submit button, submits data to self for validation
3. Data is redisplayed, and action is pointed to insert script
4. Submit button, submits data to insert script

The problem is, between 3 and 4 the user COULD change the data, bypassing validation and submit different data.

Validation should ALWAYS be done in the same script as your database queries (yes, even for select queries).

Either put your database queries in with your validation (if valid), or put your validation checks in with your database queries.  Then remove any conditional action for your form, and just let it submit.

Answer (score 0):

You described exactly what your issue is in the question. When your page renders for the first time the action is `PHP_SELF`. You then have to click the submit button (1 time) to change the action based on the value of `$valid`. Once that is done and you click submit again (2 times) then you can successfully submit.

To fix this you need to not stop the form from submitting to `validate1.php`. So do this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style> .error {color:#ff0000;} </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myform" method="post" action="validate1.php" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Company Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="companyName" value ="<?php if(isset($_POST['companyName']) && empty($companyNameErr)){ echo $_POST['companyName'];} else {echo '';}?>" required ><span class="error"><sup>*</sup><?php echo $companyNameErr; ?></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="address" value ="<?php if(isset($_POST['address']) && empty($addressErr)){ echo $_POST['address'];} else {echo '';}?>" required><span class="error"><sup>*</sup><?php echo $addressErr; ?></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" value ="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']) && empty($emailErr)){ echo $_POST['email'];} else {echo '';}?>" required><span class="error"><sup>*</sup><?php echo $emailErr; ?></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contact</td>
                    <td>+91-<input type="text" name="contact" value ="<?php if(isset($_POST['contact']) && empty($contactErr)){ echo $_POST['contact'];} else {echo '';}?>" required maxlength="10" minlength="10"><span class="error"><sup>*</sup><?php echo $contactErr; ?></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td><textarea name="description" cols="60" rows="3"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="next>>">
        </form>
    </body>
```

Now you are submitted to `validate1.php` and can do validation like what you had at the top of of the form before. If the form is clean submit it to the database else re-render the form with the data and error messages submitting back to `validate1.php` to try again.